# How to feed wild frog?

Tags: feeding, frogs

I have a well which is 12 feet deep and now I couldn’t dry the well.

One green black frog has jumped in the well. Its been a week now. There is no food for it to eat. If we drop some earthworms to the brim of each ring next to the water, it will move and go to the bottom. I don’t think frogs can go that deep.

I tried to catch it to free it, but when I bring the net, it goes underwater.

It was active at first. But now it is lying in water in a strange way. His legs are weak.

**So my question is, is there any good idea to feed it. Or to get it out of my well.**

And also what are the foods that can be given to the frog in this situation.

I would really not like to see it die.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a bucket and tie a rope on the handle to be able to lift it back out. Fill the bucket to the brim with water and then place a piece of wood - any short board or slat or even a piece of branch - into the bucket. Lower the bucket into the well and tie it off so that the rim is just the tiniest bit below the water surface. Walk away for a few minutes.

This setup should make the wood float on top of the water, but the rim of the bucket still high enough to not let it float away. The frog should naturally prefer the wood as a place to rest. Since the wood in always inside the bucket, you can pull the bucket out as soon as you see the frog on or near the wood. If the frog dives down, it will still be in the bucket and you can lift it out.

As for food, if you happen to have mosquito larvae in a rain barrel or so, put some (but not too many) in the bucket. You can also swat a fly and put it on the wood, but it must be a very fresh one. If you happen to have any maggots anywhere, those are good, too and you can place them on the wood. An earthworm probably has to be cut into smaller pieces, since frogs don't have teeth.

Comment: That seems like it would work. I will let you know.

Comment: The frog is sitting on the branch which is made stuck in the bucket but when I’m lifting the bucket, it’s jumping out to the well itself. It is not jumping into the bucket. And it is not taking the earthworms left in the bucket. I have already cut them into small pieces.

Comment: @Browniepoints Hmm, I didn't forsee that :(

Comment: But I never even thought of that. I also thought it would work. Maybe, it will eat the earthworms after a few days. It might be scared.

Comment: Today, I tried the bucket trick using a bucket with holes and quickly lifted. I was able to get the frog out. But it is so tired it can’t move. I took to a ditch. Hope it lives. Thank you for your idea.